# Error: can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send an argument with `res.redirect()`. However, I'm getting an error while running it, saying that I cannot set headers after they are sent.

What does that mean, and how can I fix it?

```
app.post('/updateCollaborateRequest', function(req,res) {
    if(req.body.accept == true) {
        Team.findOne({'name': req.body.data.teamName}, function (err, team) {
            if(err) {
                res.redirect('/explore');
            }
            team.accepted = true;
            team.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
                Request.findOne({'emailAdmin': req.session.email}, function(err, request) {
                    request.seen = true;
                    request.save(function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
                res.redirect("/teamprof/" + team.name);
            });
        });
    }
    Request.findOne({'emailAdmin': req.session.email}, function(err, request) {
        request.seen = true;
        request.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.render('userprof1', {message : req.flash('done')});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Aside from the _really_ unacceptable begging in this post, which was edited out, I notice there are two answers below that remain unreplied to. Did either of them help you at the time? I see you've [posted again today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894865/how-to-identify-the-encoding-charset-of-a-file-in-java) - please allow me to encourage you to interact with the helpful answers you receive. It's worth considering that this site succeeds or fails on the basis of its community spirit, as well as its gamification.

Comment: Hi halfer, I apologize for the way I used the forum to ask questions. I'm certainly unaware of the fact of how to ask questions at stackoverflow, will try to keep them in mind next time. And as far as I can remember neither of the answer helped me regarding this question, and it's been a long time so I don't know what the correct solution was at that time.

Comment: Well, OK. I may be in danger of stating the obvious here, but they tried to help you, and it would be normal to interact with them, reply, or upvote for effort. I don't think this is at all particular to Stack Overflow - aren't expressions of gratitude part of ordinary human interaction?

Comment: Well as far as remember they tried to help me, but there was something else which solved the problem. And your concern about the reply, I was caught in the project as it was my final year project so forget to reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is continuing after redirecting. That is probably the problem. You should return, otherwise you are going to keep trying to write to the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error message is caused by code paths that lead to multiple `res.xxx()` calls that try to send the response more than once.

You have multiple places where you are doing that.  For example, you have two `res.redirect()` calls inside the `Team.findOne()` callback, but then you proceed with `Request.findOne()` where you have a `res.render()`.  You HAVE to make sure that you only send the response once.

I'm not entirely sure what the desired logic is in all cases, but you can fix that error by adding an `else` statement before the `Request.findOne()` and adding a `return` after each `res.redirect()`.  If this is not the exactly flow you want, then please explain more about how you want the control flow to work.  Here's the code with those changes applied:

```
app.post('/updateCollaborateRequest', function(req,res) {
    if(req.body.accept == true) {
        Team.findOne({'name': req.body.data.teamName}, function (err, team) {
            if(err) {
                res.redirect('/explore');
                return;
            }
            team.accepted = true;
            team.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    // FIXME: need error handling here
                    alert(err);
                }
                Request.findOne({'emailAdmin': req.session.email}, function(err, request) {
                    request.seen = true;
                    request.save(function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            // FIXME: need error handling here
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
                // Are you sure you want to send this response before
                // you even know if the `Request.findOne()` and `request.save()` 
                // have been sucessful?
                res.redirect("/teamprof/" + team.name);
                return;
            });
        });
    } else {
        Request.findOne({'emailAdmin': req.session.email}, function(err, request) {
            request.seen = true;
            request.save(function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                res.render('userprof1', {message : req.flash('done')});
            });
        });
    }
});
```

You still have several error conditions for which no response is sent which is incomplete error handling so those need to be fixed too.  And, I've added some comments in the code about some other suspect things in the code.