# How to identify the encoding charset of a file in Java?

Tags: java

I've already tried the juniversalchardet library and it works fine for UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE but it's not detecting the format for US_ASCII and ISO-8859-1. I've also used the jchardet and it doesn't achieve my goal.

Plus the InputStreamReader is not also working in my situation. So, how can I detect the character-sets US_ASCII and ISO-8859-1, or for all the of the above character sets?

Incidentally, I created these format files using editpad Lite 7.

Comment: AFAIR US_ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. Therefore if an text only contains ASCII characters all three encodings can be used. Hence there is no "correct" charset to be detected, as all three are correct. May be this is what you are facing. Try to use texts that use characters that only exist in ISO-8859-1 and see the results.

Comment: The encoding of the text file should come with the file's bytes in the same or a separate communication or via convention, specification, etc. Why are you trying to guess it? You could guess it from one sample and then it be wrong for the next update to it. Oh, if you saved the files, then you are the one determining the encoding.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned there is no *certain* way to detect encoding. But there is a large amount of heuristics that allow to do a *smart guess* about file encoding.

If there is no way for you to get to know the encoding for sure you may have a look at [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) project and [EncodingDetector](https://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/org/apache/tika/detect/EncodingDetector.html) there.

Comment: hi, thanks for guiding me towards Apache tika, I didn't used encodingDetector as it wasn't sufficient for me, but ICU4J is very good.

Comment: For me as well I had more success with ICU4J

Answer (score 1):

By the sheer nature of character encodings, character encoding detectors cannot possibly be 100% reliable. They can only give a best guess.

ASCII is a subset of all other 8-bit encodings, consisting of code points in the range 0 to 127 (i.e. all values can be represented in just 7 bits). This means that if your file contains only ASCII characters, it can be read using ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2, etc., and UTF-8. I would expect a good charset detector to tell you if the contents are pure ASCII, so I don't know why juniversalchardet didn't when you tried it.

It's tricky to tell the various single-byte encodings apart. For example, the character £ is a valid character in ISO-8859-1 but is equally valid (but displayed differently) in ISO-8859-2 and other encodings. So it's not easy to tell which character was actually intended.

Comment: and adding UTF-16LE/UTF-16BE into the mix doesn't make it easier either: represent the two bytes 0x41 0x42 now the string "AB" (in US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8) or do the represent han characters (either U+4142 in UTF-16BE http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4142/index.htm or U+4241 in UTF-16LE http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4441/index.htm)?

Comment: Well, they can be 100% reliable in this sense: Definitely not those character encodings but possibly these that it knows of, for the source as it is right now. I guess what gets people is that some report just one of the possibilities, perhaps the smallest or most common in some respect.

Comment: @ThomasKläger The U+ notation is for Unicode codepoints and is written in hexadecimal with the mathematically conventional 1's place on the right. If you are talking about UTF-16 code units they are the one '\u4142' for the codepoint you cited. Only when you view the integer 0x4142 as bytes does endianness come into play: 0x41 0x42 (BE) or 0x42 0x41 (LE).

Comment: @TomBlodget I can represent the Unicode codepoint U+4142 in a java string as "\u4142". If I convert this string into a byte array using the "UTF-16BE" encoding (with `"\u4142".getBytes("UTF-16BE")`), I get a two bytes long byte array containing the values 0x41 and 0x42. If I write the Unicode codepoint U+4241 in a java string a would write "\u4241". Converting this string into a byte array using "UTF-16LE" encoding (`"\u4241".getBytes("UTF-16LE")`), I get the same two bytes long byte array with the values 0x41 and 0x42. So just from those two bytes I cannot decide what the original string was

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I misread your first comment. Your point is a good one.

Comment: Thank you guys, your answer actually allowed me to detect file encodings correctly. As the problem which I was facing was the inconsistent data being stored in the database if the file character set doesn't match the provided one. So before using the ICU4J library which was really helpful, I checked if there is any special character or not. If it's not then the character set is valid always.

Answer (score 0):

ICU4J worked better than Tika for me.

Method prints the match confidence in % and the encoding.

```
public static String readFileAsStringGuessEncoding(String filePath) {
    String s = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(fileData);
        dis.close();

        CharsetMatch match = new CharsetDetector().setText(fileData).detect();
        if (match != null) {
            try {
                String fileName = filePath;
                System.out.printf("Encoding: %15s confidence: %03d  File: %s \n\r", match.getName(), match.getConfidence(), fileName);

                s = new String(fileData, match.getName());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ue) {
                s = null;
            }
        }

        if (s == null) {
            s = new String(fileData);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>71.1</version>
    </dependency>
```